# Are you supposed to write javadoc after or before you start programming?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd

I think javadocs are beautiful. Clear descriptions for each method and class. Our tester can easily write unit-tests without repetitive explanations from programmers.

This is how we practice TDD at our start-up. We first sit and plan the application structure, and we start creating all the methods and classes (without programming), we add descriptions to the classes, constructors and methods with javadoc. We then ship this to our tester who write unit tests. When he is done, we start programming.

No one is actually complaining. Our tester is in love with javadoc and although he is a terrible programmer (that is why he became a tester), he can easily understand the javadoc and write junit-tests.

The thing is, most of us are newbies in a start-up. And I don't know if you are supposed to document all the classes and methods before we even start programming? My question to you more experienced programmers is: is this a good TDD approach?

Comment: Aside from anything else, that quite sound test-driven to me... the tester isn't involved in the design, from what you've said. One of the aims of test-driven development is to ensure that the code is testable, by writing the tests first... with the expectation that a design which is easy to test is also easy to use.

Comment: NOOOO. YOU should test your own code. Not a tester. The tests and the documentation should evolve as the production code evolves. While programming, you'll realize there are corner cases that need to be documented and tested.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you. The developer should write the unit tests on his own. I haven't come across such a model of working till date where someone else writes the unit tests on my behalf.

Comment: @JonSkeet No, only the programmers are involved in the design of the application. The tester is responsible for all the testing.

Comment: @JBNizet Why not? Writing unit-tests is not rocket science, and our tester is not having any issues with it.

Comment: So in what sense is this test-driven development or test-driven design? Or do you mean something else by TDD?

Comment: @SishuanKen if you consider your tester too bad a programmer to appreciate the quality of the design and participate in the conception, How can you find flaws in the design if he's the only one to actually use the code you produce?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't understand your point. The tester is responsible for testing, and the programmers are responsible for programming. The tester write tests before we start programming, and we strive to meet the requirement of his test so they all pass. Is this not TDD?

Comment: No, it's not. Your design isn't being informed by the tests. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

Comment: @JonSkeet Our tester is well informed of the code structure and design. We give him a detailed explanation of all our classes and methods during the whole project.

Comment: No, you've missed my point. In TDD, the tests *drive the design of the code*. (Note that I talked about "the tests inform the design" not "the tester is informed of the design" - those are *very* different things.) In your case, you've already defined the design before the tests are written. You can like it as a process, of course, but it's not TDD.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry if I misunderstood you. Let me give you an example of how we work: 
Let's say that we are going to build a calculator. We then plan what classes and method we are going to use. We then start writing unit-tests for the methods and classes. All the tests fail in the beginning, and we code until all the tests pass. Still not TDD? If not, please correct my example.
If you don't know what a function does then you can't write a unit test for it. For all you know it doesn't even do what it's supposed to. You need to find out what it's supposed to do first. THEN write the test.

Comment: @SishuanKen if you were using TDD, you'd realize while writing the tests that the initial design you had in mind is not adequate, or could be better, and the tests would help you discover that and change the design. You'd also realize while writing the code and the tests that a corner-case had not been anticipated and needs to be documented and tested. You would thus proceed by short cycles, where the tests would change the code, and the code would change the tests. What you're doing is big upfront design.

Comment: @JBNizet We are NOT righting everything on stone. I know that design can be improved or changed, and if we do so, the requirements for the tests change as well.

Comment: Nothing forces you to use TDD. If you like the way you're doing, then fine. Just don't assume you're doing TDD, because that's not how TDD is defined.

Comment: No, still not TDD. You're not discovering the design via tests. It may well work for you, but it's not TDD.

Comment: This is likely a bit off topic, but, dang, I wanna work where you do. 5% of the existing code I  work with has comments.

Comment: @JonSkeet I feel totally lost right now. I thought TDD was: you first write a failing test, then you code until your test pass. What have I missed?

Comment: You've missed the part where your tests are a key driving factor in the design. In your process, they can't be - because you're coming up with the design before any tests are written. In extreme (or "true" depending on your definitions) TDD, the first "failing test" fails because it doesn't even compile. You then make it compile, but then it fails by giving the wrong answer. You then make it pass. Then, and only then, do you move on to the next piece of functionality.

Comment: @JonSkeet We are deciding the functionality of each individual component. If we do not do this, how on earth are we going to create an application? Is deciding the functionality and deciding the design the same thing?

Comment: Pretty much - not just the overall functionality, but the exact method signatures etc as well. The point is that if you make tests the way of driving that forward, you end up with testable code. Again, I'm not saying that what you're doing isn't working for you - I'm just saying it's not TDD.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I am not stealing too much of your time, can you give me a TDD example with the calculator example I gave before? Thank you.

Comment: @JonSkeet How do you practice TDD if you don't know what a function does which you can't write a unit test for it?

Comment: @SishuanKen: You imagine what you want to be able to do, and write a test which expresses that in the most natural way possible (making it easy to write the test). That then teaches you what the production code should look like.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you Jon Skeet. You are a nice man. :

Answer (score 2):

TDD is useful, because it makes sure you do not miss any requirements. It ends up beings used as unit test cases, and while the programmer starts their work they need to make sure all the test cases are covered.

Testers write system & integration test cases.

coming to javadoc, ideally it should be a must. It removes code duplication/reusablity and also adds some value to system document.

Javadoc should describe the return type, input params and process being carried out within the method.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted to ask, but I could not find the correct words. Thank you Saurabh for your good answer.